# Query with a JOIN table not returning any result

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo

Would you know why my query does not return any value after `echo res:`? (`res:` appears well, but nothing after).

I have got one table named Person, and a JOIN table named people_friends :

```
CREATE TABLE person (
  idperson integer primary key,
  name VARCHAR(50)
);
CREATE TABLE people_friends (
  person_id integer,
  otherPerson_id integer,
  primary key (person_id, otherPerson_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (person_id)
    REFERENCES person (idperson),
  FOREIGN KEY (otherPerson_id)
    REFERENCES person (idperson));
```

And the query :

```
<?php
//CONNECT
    try {
        $connection = new PDO('pgsql:host='.$PARAM_host.';dbname='.$PARAM_db_name, $PARAM_user, $PARAM_password);    
        echo "test";
    }
catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo 'Error : '.$e->getMessage().'<br />';
        echo 'N° : '.$e->getCode();
    }

//QUERY
    try {
        echo '<br/>qsdf<br/>';
        $q = "SELECT p.idperson, p.name FROM person p INNER JOIN people_friends pf ON p.idperson = pf.person_id";
        $res = $connection->query($q);
        $res->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo "res : ".$res->name;
    }
catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo 'Error : '.$e->getMessage().'<br />';
        echo 'N° : '.$e->getCode();
    }

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: You're fetching an associative array; but using the object syntax to get the values. Try `$res['name']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to fetch records. It should be:

```
...

$res->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($record = $res->fetch()) {
    var_dump($record['name']);
}

...
```